# Stroke width estimation

Tags: opencv, image-processing

i found an algorithm which is about "stroke width estimation". The aim of the algorithm is to estimate size that will be use as kernel or structuring element for opening and closing operation. I have tried to implement it in opencv. The algorithm, i took from journal by Mou-Yen Chen "Off-line Handwritten Word Recognition Using Hidden Markov Model Type Stochastic Network" :

1. For each column, count the number of black pixels and the transitions between black and white i.e the number of runs
2. Estimate maxwidth by --> maxwidth = (no. of black pixels / total no. of runs) * 1.5
3. Repeat step 1 after discarding those black pixels whose run length is greater than maxwidth
4. The estimated width is the count of black pixels divided by the count of runs.

Here is the sample image, i have been binarized :

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_g1PNBVdIpGM1EyU0lNdHd1ZU0

For the first step, my code :

```
int numOfBlack = 0;
int numOfRun = 0;

for(int i=0;i<thresholdImg.cols;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<thresholdImg.rows;j++){
    if(thresholdImg.at<uchar>(j,i)==0){
      numOfBlack++;
      if((j+1)<thresholdImg.rows){
        if(thresholdImg.at<uchar>(j+1,i)>0){
          numOfRun++;
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

For the second step, my code :

```
double maxWidth = ((numOfBlack*1.0)/(numOfRun*1.0))*1.5;
```

And for the third step, i don't know how to do it, basically i think like this :

```
int numOfBlack2 = 0;
int numOfRun2 = 0;

for(int i=0;i<thresholdImg.cols;i++){
  int coba = 0;
  int cobaRun = 0;
  for(int j=0;j<thresholdImg.rows;j++){
    if(thresholdImg.at<uchar>(j,i)==0){
      coba++;
      if((j+1)<thresholdImg.rows){
        if(thresholdImg.at<uchar>(j+1,i)>0){
          cobaRun++;
        }
      }
    }

  }

  cout<<cobaRun<<endl;

  if((cobaRun*1.0<=maxWidth)){
    numOfBlack2+=coba;
    numOfRun2+=cobaRun;
  }
}
```

And for the fourth step :

```
double strokeWitdth = ((numOfBlack2*1.0)/(numOfRun2*1.0));
```

Actually, i confuse in the third step. Can anyone help me ? because i am completely stuck in the third step. 
Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an example image? Are the strokes horizontal? Or vertical?

Comment: And a link to the algorthm, and a description of what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: @barny i have edited my question and also there is a sample image.